# How to show mySQL BLOB data

Tags: 7, database

Is there a simple way to look at BLOB data that Drupal 7 stores in some tables?

There is a [trick to configure phpmyadmin](http://groups.drupal.org/node/134269) but apparently it's not working with version 3.3.9.2 that comes with MAMP.

Comment: The free version of [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_mysql/mysql_overview.html) lets you view `BLOB` fields as text very easily...I've been using it for many years now and it plays nicely with MAMP

Comment: that worked, thanks! Any way of rendering the json krumo style to be able to inspect it better?

Comment: If only it _was_ JSON there would be a couple of different ways to browse it, but unfortunately it's a serialised PHP object :/ You might get away with doing something like: `dpm(unserialize('DUMP_BLOB_HERE'));` in code but I haven't tried it out

Comment: This [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12141156/686654) worked for me, there are others mentioned there.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to peek, say into user-­­­>data, which is seralised data array, just use `drush sqlc` to bring yourself to an sql command line, then type:

```
 select uid, name data from users where uid = <whateveruidyouwant>;
```

This works for any data, and if you are brave you can even edit the serialized data via command-line but is not recommended unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I would json_encode the array into a variable and spit it out via devel.

```
$var = json_encode($yourarray); 
dpm($var);
```